# AWS Elastic Beanstalk (eb) installation in Ubuntu 14.04: command not found

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

Im trying to install AWS eb command line interface in Ubuntu 14.04. I just donwloaded the .zip file. Extracted in a folder. if I go to folder where eb is (/home/roberto/app/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.1/eb/linux/python2.7) and run it, I get: eb: command not found

Same if I do it with python3 path.

Comment: Fixed: I just run: export PATH=$PATH:/opt/aws/eb/linux/python2.7/ and itś working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed:

I just ran the command on a terminal:

```sh
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/aws/eb/linux/python2.7/
```

and it's working.

Comment: or just add `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH ` to you profile

Comment: @Aleem: right, that's also what these [instructions from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html) suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you have to do is, upgrade awsebcli by running: `pip install --upgrade awsebcli`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using arch linux:

Find your shell's profile script, in case of bash use .bash_profile
run

```
$ ls -a ~

$ nano profile_script`   #in my case `$ nano .bash_profile
```

Add

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Save and exit.

Now run

```
$source ~/profile_script
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu we write like :
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

It worked for me after writing this because eb folder will be present inside mentioned folder.